# One die is rolled three times - probability outcome of third roll is between first two?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

A die is rolled 3 times, what is the probability that the third launch has an outcome that is strictly included between the other two?

An explanation would also be very appreciated as I’m not a mathematician.

Thank you!

Comment: First, as a nitpick, the singular noun is "Die."  The plural noun is "Dice."  We roll one die.  We roll many dice.  Next, it should be mentioned that the die in question is a fair six-sided die since that is important to the problem and other types of dice exist.  As for the math involved... note that there are $6\times 6\times 6$ different possible outcomes for having thrown the die three times in sequence, each of which are equally likely to have occurred.  So, just count the number of favorable events and take the ratio to find the probability.

Comment: As for counting the number of favorable events... consider the use of binomial coefficients.  For the second problem in particular, consider breaking into cases based on how many distinct numbers actually appeared (whether all three numbers were different, the first and second were equal and the third different, all three are equal, etc...)

Comment: @JMoravitz That looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to look at this without exhaustively making a list of all the outcomes. The only way the above is possible is when the three numbers are distinct (otherwise strict inequality won't be satisfied)

$$P(\text{distinct numbers}) = \frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{6\cdot 6\cdot 6}$$

Now, in an arrangement of distinct numbers, there are two ways out of 6 total permutations that the condition can be satisfied

$$P = \frac{2}{6}\cdot P(\text{distinct numbers}) = \frac{5}{27}$$

Comment: This is a an answer to the first question.

Comment: Oh didn't see that bit ,will edit